# Subtraction of Date and time

Tags: java, arrays, date

I am trying to subtract the date and time of two consecutive lines from a file, like doing:

```
String result1=line2-line1;
String result2=line4-line3;
// and so on.........
```

A sample file content could be the following:

```
 Thu Jan 16 2014 16:59:43.5020 
 Thu Jan 16 2014 16:59:43.5020 
 Thu Jan 16 2014 16:59:43.5020 
 Thu Jan 16 2014 16:59:43.5090 
 Thu Jan 16 2014 16:59:43.5100 
 Thu Jan 16 2014 16:59:43.5100 
 Thu Jan 16 2014 16:59:43.5170 
 Thu Jan 16 2014 16:59:43.9190 
 Thu Jan 16 2014 16:59:43.9200 
 Thu Jan 16 2014 16:59:43.9200 
 Thu Jan 16 2014 16:59:43.9200 
 Thu Jan 16 2014 16:59:43.9210 
 Thu Jan 16 2014 16:59:43.9210 
 Thu Jan 16 2014 16:59:43.9210 
 Thu Jan 16 2014 16:59:43.9210 
 Thu Jan 16 2014 16:59:43.9210 
 Thu Jan 16 2014 16:59:43.9220 
 Thu Jan 16 2014 16:59:43.9290 
 Thu Jan 16 2014 16:59:43.9290 
 Thu Jan 16 2014 16:59:43.9290 
 Thu Jan 16 2014 16:59:43.9330 
 Thu Jan 16 2014 16:59:44.0210 
 Thu Jan 16 2014 16:59:44.0210 
 Thu Jan 16 2014 16:59:44.0210
```

Comment: Pls ask something when you write a question.

Comment: Hi guys, i am trying to extract difference between these two timings for consecutive lines. like Result(70 ms)=(Thu Jan 16 2014 16:59:43.5090) -(Thu Jan 16 2014 16:59:43.5020) and So on.....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculating the Difference Between Two Java Date Instances](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555262/calculating-the-difference-between-two-java-date-instances)

Comment: @MaduBiradar Edit the Question for clarity, rather than using a comment. Notice the "edit" link at lower-left of the Question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have get the context of the file. string line1 contain the text from firstline,string line2contain text from the second line.

```
    int datedifference=Integer.parseInt(line2.substring(8,10))-Integer.parseInt(line1.substring(8,10));
    int yeardifference=Integer.parseInt(line2.substring(11,15))-Integer.parseInt(line1.substring(11,15));
    int hourdifference=Integer.parseInt(line2.substring(16,18))-Integer.parseInt(line1.substring(16,18));
    int minutedifference=Integer.parseInt(line2.substring(19,21))-Integer.parseInt(line1.substring(19,21));
    int seconddifference=Integer.parseInt(line2.substring(22,23))-Integer.parseInt(line1.substring(22,23));
    int lastthingdifference=Integer.parseInt(line2.substring(24,28))-Integer.parseInt(line1.substring(24,28));
```

Then you got all int you need , just realign it the way you like

Note:For date you may have to set a logic which convert the days to int.

Cheers

Comment: What if the number of the day is only 1 digit?

Comment: Int do not have 02 value, it changes to 2 automatically , but I admit my code have some problem if line2 values are less than line1 values , It's the OP to choose what to use

Comment: @Poomrokc, Thanks Good Effort, in my case there will not be chance to have less values in second than first..

Comment: @Poomrokc, I am reading these lines from a file and i am using BufferedReader and also while((String str=buff.readLine())!=null){  what else small modification needed, i am trying but its not giving result for my file}  please few help needed..appreciate your help

Comment: @MaduBiradar I think you got helped from DayaMoon , do you still need my help?

Comment: @Poomrokc, here what i tried. i am new to java,i am student.                                              DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyyHH:mm:ss.SSSS", 
                                      Locale.ENGLISH); while((str=br.readLine())!=null)
{
String next=br.readLine();
int datedifference=Integer.parseInt(next.substring(8,10))Integer.parseInt(str.substring(8,10));                                                          System.out.println(datediffrenece);                   System.out.println(df.parse(next).getTime()-df.parse(str).getTime());

Comment: @ Poomrokc ,your code is correct but i am not able to put it into proper way i want i.e DATE,TIME type conversion and all those things so help needed..

Comment: @all, I am getting errror like this....                     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " 1"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:569)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
 at project.Subtract.main(Subtract.java:49)
Java Result: 1

Answer (score 1):

With subtaction

`DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSSS", 
                                      Locale.ENGLISH);`

`System.out.println( df.parse(line2).getTime() - df.parse(line1).getTime() );`

Answer (score 0):

try the below code...

you can implement the basic logic as per your need

```
String string1 = "Oct 15, 2012 1:07:13 PM";
String string2 = "Oct 23, 2012 03:43:34 PM";
//here you want to mention the format that you want
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss a", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date date1 = sdf.parse(string1);
Date date2 = sdf.parse(string2);
//to found difference between two dates
long differenceInMillis = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
```

Comment: I have this code already from this website only but its not reading line by line and subtracting two consecutive lines.I am looking Like-- diff_Result=(Second_line)-(First_line);                       diff_Result=(Fourth_line)-(Third_line);

Comment: for that just store all those values in an array and construct one for loop in that intialise two variables like i=0 and j=1 and each and every time you just increment those values like - for(i=0,j=1;i<arrayname.length;i++,j++){//here u can write ur code}

Comment: Thanks for your effort and explaination

Answer (score 0):

This will trim off any white spaces also...i got this here you should be very careful to mention the index of string which you would like to extract and subtract for example:

```
 startIndex:starts from index 0(inclusive).

 endIndex:starts from index 1(exclusive).
```

int datedifference=Integer.parseInt(line2.substring(8,10).trim())-Integer.parseInt(line1.substring(8,10).trim());

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
Duration.between(                               // Calculate and represent the span of time elapsed.
    LocalDateTime.parse(                        // Parse the input string as a `LocalDateTime` because it lacks any indicator of time zone or offset-from-UTC.
        "Thu Jan 16 2014 16:59:43.5020" ,       // Work with each pair of input strings.
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "EEE MMM dd uuuu HH:mm:ss.SSSS" , Locale.US )  // Define a formatting pattern to match your input. Specify human language for translation via `Locale` object.
    ) ,
    LocalDateTime.parse(
        "Thu Jan 16 2014 16:59:43.5090" , 
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "EEE MMM dd uuuu HH:mm:ss.SSSS" , Locale.US )
    ) 
)
```

## File lines

Read your file in as a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/List.html) of lines.

```
List< String > lines = Files.readAllLines( pathGoesHere ) ;
```

## ISO 8601

By the way, the format used in your Question is terrible.

Whenever possible, use only standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats for serializing date-time values to text.

## java.time

The modern approach uses the industry-leading *java.time* classes that supplanted the troublesome old legacy classes such as `Date`/`Calendar`/`SimpleDateFormat`.

Define a formatting pattern matching each line. Note the `Locale` argument specifying the human language and cultural norms to be used in translating the text.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "EEE MMM dd uuuu HH:mm:ss.SSSS" , Locale.US ) ;  // Thu Jan 16 2014 16:59:43.5020
```

Parse each input line as [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) because the input lacks any indicator of time zone or offset-from-UTC.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( "Thu Jan 16 2014 16:59:43.5020" , f  );
```

> ldt.toString(): 2014-01-16T16:59:43.502

Loop your input lines, cache each pair, and compare. Calculate and represent the span of time elapsed using [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) class.

```
for( int index = 0 , index < lines.size() , index + 2 ) { // Increment by two, as we are processing pairs together.
    String inputStart = lines.get( index ) ;
    LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.parse( inputStart , f  ) ;

    String inputStop = lines.get( index + 1 ) ;  // Move index to second of this pair of lines.
    LocalDateTime stop = LocalDateTime.parse( inputStop , f  ) ;

    // Calculate the time elapsed using generic 24-hour based days, as we lack any time zone or offset-from-UTC.
    Duration d = Duration.between( start , stop ) ; 
}
```

You can use that `Duration` object in various ways:

- Ask for a total number of seconds, minutes, etc.
- Ask for each part: hours and minutes and seconds and fractional second by calling the `to…Part` method.
- Generate a String in standard [ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS` where the `P` marks the beginning and the `T` separates any years-months-days from the hours-minutes-seconds.
- Pass to the `plus`/`minus` methods found on various *java.time* classes.

### Time zone

Be aware that the solution above is not trustworthy in that a `LocalDateTime` does *not* represent a moment, is *not* a point on the timeline. To determine a moment, you must place that `LocalDateTime` into the context of a particular time zone. Until then it has no real meaning. The `Duration` calculation is done using generic 24-hour days without regard for anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST).

If you know for certain the time zone in which that input data was intended, apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  
ZonedDateTime zdtStart = start.atZone( z ) ;
```

Then proceed with calculating the `Duration`.

```
Duration d = Duration.between( zdtStart , zdtStop ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).